# CSS errors (at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)) and ({ expectedcss(css-lcurlyexpected))

Tags: css

How can I solve these 2 errors as in the pictures below.
Pic1:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBxbs.jpg
Pic2:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKgdi.jpg

I have never seen such errors in CSS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the picture. You may have to restart the editor. If this continues upload the whole code here. I think cade above this error may have something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
@media screen (max-width: 763px) and (min-width: 500px) {
  .hero_section {
    margin: 55px 0px;
  }
  .hero_section .row h1 {
    font-size: 46px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero_section .row h2 {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero_section .row p {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero_section .btn_container {
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

  }
  .hero_section .row h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .hero_section .row::after {
    width: 0px;
  }
  .hero_section .btn_container button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 43px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;    
} 

.hero_section img {
      width: 60%;
      margin-top: 20px;
  } 
}
```